# Mystical Creatures- Lycanthropes and Werewovles coexisting

Tags: politics, mythical-creatures, shapeshifters

In the Order many mythical creatures live together, including Lycanthropes and Werewolves, under the High Council, which ensures justice and enforces peace

The main difference between the two is that Lycanthropes can change when they want to, and Werewolves have to have the moon present to be able change.
So the problem is with the Werewolves, as they feel that they are not seen as important member of the Order, and are looking for ways to be included in the greater society.

At present they are treated like the rest of the humans that live within the Order. There is nothing in the form of laws to help their situation at present, as Werewolf status is not accepted unless someone has seen the transformation take place or has seen the mark placing the individual as a Werewolf.

There are no laws protecting Werewolves only Lycanthropes, as Lycanthropes have strict laws they are subject to ensure the safety of those around them, as they do not want their kind growing exponentially. The Werewolves want the problems they have with the species that see them as lesser dealt with.

With this the High Council has not known how to proceed, the issue was brought to their attention 5 years ago, and nothing has moved forward towards a decision if how to help.

Comment: Some advice: format your question. Seeing one big block of text is intimidating to most readers and is genuinely hard to read in any case; separate it into sections (problem, differences between werewolves and lycanthropes, historical background, and current political/legal structure would probably be what you need in this case) of however many paragraphs each. Right now, when I look at your question, I have no idea if the Order is a government, a private organization, a secret society, etc., and that alone is something that can produce very different answers.

Comment: It's considered poor form to accept and answer within 24 hours of asking the question. By waitingt 24 hours people from every timezone can answer.

Comment: I have deleted vampires, since I feel that (although nice in-universe twilight joke) does not relate to the question.

Comment: What about werebears? Bakemono? Skin-walkers. Do only wolf > human transformations exist in your universe?

Comment: I don't see any question. Indeed the question post does not contain a single question mark. What do you want to know?

Comment: @b.Lorenz Your added explanation (question revision 2) does not appear to be supported by content provided by the OP. Making edits that deviate from the original intent of the post, including adding additional material not supported by what the OP has written, is discouraged. If your edit is supported by comments, you may want to make that explicit in the edit summary in case the relevant comments are later deleted; doing so will at least preserve *some* kind of trail of evidence.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I assume you think of my first sentence (the others are just rearranging the original, unformated text) This is based the earlier, overly board question of the OP. It seemed to me, that OP stepped to this new question without realizing that he didn't explain the nature of his mythical creature society again. I tried to help, but if I was incorrect, feel free to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Since equality before the law already exists, the best they can do is helping Werewolves getting their Werewolf status, and then give extra opportunities to the Werewolves.**

So may they establish the Werewolf Certification Institute. It opens at fullmoon, anybody can walk in, transform under controlled circumstances, and get a Certificate about being Werewolf. They have to find something, in which werewolves are better than Lycanthropes. Maybe they are not so great shock troopers, since they can not transform on will into a raging bear, but they can communicate better with an ordinary wolf... Find a job that only a Certificated Real Werewolf can complete, and award their success open-handedly.

And of course, ban and punish any public racist insult against the Werewolves (from Lycanthropes, Shapeshifters, Berserkers, Wargs or anybody else)